# BehaviorSubject as an observer

Tags: rxjs5, behaviorsubject

This code shows nothing in console. But if i change the second line with the commented code it works. Is this expected or something wrong here?

```
let bSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1);
of(2).subscribe(bSubject); // of(2).subscribe(data => bSubject.next(data));
bSubject.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is by-design.

The first `subscribe` call sees the subject's `complete` method called, as the source observable completes.

Once the subject's `complete` method is called, the `BehaviorSubject` is done and no further values will be emitted.

That is, calling `next` on a completed `BehaviorSubject` will not emit a value and subscribing to a completed `BehaviorSubject` won't emit an initial value.

When you replace the second line with:

```
of(2).subscribe(data => bSubject.next(data));
```

The subject's `complete` will no longer be called when the source observable completes and the subsequent subscription to the subject will emit the subject's current value.